# Черный экран vlc xamrin.forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, vlc

Видео воспроизводиться нормально, но если открыть другое приложение и вернуться, то vlc будет показывать черный экран со звуком. (Android 8.0.0, последняя версия nuget пакетов)

```js
LibVLC libVLC = new LibVLC("--preferred-resolution=-1", " --log-verbose=3", "--no-gnutls-system-trust");
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
Media media = new Media(libVLC, playerUrl, FromType.FromLocation);
VideoView1.MediaPlayer = mediaPlayer;
mediaPlayer.Play();
```

Comment: Предположу, что вам нужно [это](https://code.videolan.org/mfkl/libvlcsharp-samples/tree/master/ForegroundBackground)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, посмотрю

Comment: Быть может стоит автоматом ставить на паузу при сворачивании? Либо останавливать видео, а прои возобновлении работы приложения просто начать воспроизведение с того же места.

Comment: А судя по коду у вас `mediaPlayer` null, вы его просто не создаете. Возникает исключение. Или где-то потерялась часть кода.

Comment: @epot нет, при сворачивании не ставится на паузу, ситуация не меняется даже если начать воспроизводить новое видео. Mediaplayer никогда не равен null и каких-либо исключений не возникает

Comment: Я пишу только про то что вижу в показанном коде. Про паузу - сделайте, чтобы ставилось, об этом я и писал, вы просто невнимательно прочитали.

Comment: @aepot я уже делал остановку на паузу- не помогло

Comment: Попробуйте сохранить тайминг и полностью остановить видео, а потом снова начать с сохраненного места.

Comment: @aepot это тоже не помогает, похоже vlc делает что-то, после чего не может нормально воспроизводить видео

Comment: Здесь уже без кода не подсказать.

Comment: Так это javascript? Я исправил подсветку кода на C#, вы откатили обратно. Если это javascript, вам нужно поменять теги на посте.

Comment: @aepot это не js, когда вы исправили оно перестало подсвечиваться

Comment: оно не перестало подвечиваться, оно стало подвечиваться, как здесь должен подвечиваться шарп. А теперь вообще по полслова подсветка, читать невозможно. Ну вам виднее.

Comment: Я вам ссылку дал, там описание проблемы, а также решение в виде подписки на события `OnPause` и `OnRestart` устройства, где идет сохранение состояние плеера и его восстановление (с полным созданием нового экземпляра плеера). Вы это пробовали? Если да, то добавляйте это в вопрос, показывайте как пробовали, объясняйте почему это не работает для вас.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, спасибо, данное вами решение работает, но я пока еще работаю над ним